# Get a value in same class selector Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used the bootstrap modal in foreach loop. Using Jquery to get the value from the text field in the modal.

`<?PHP foreach($getd as $getdetails): ?>`

```
 <a href = '#' data-toggle='modal' data-animation='bounce' data-target='.fvcmodel".$getd['id']."'>".$getd['code']."</a>


<div class="modal fade fvcmodel<?PHP echo $getd['id']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">`

<input type = "hidden" name="fvcid" id="fvcid" value="<?PHP echo $getd['id']; ?>">
<select name="billstatus" class="form-control form-control-lg billstatus">
    <option value="">Select Status</option>
    <option value="1">Bill Received in Stores</option>
     <option value="2">Returned</option>
     <option value="3">Submitted to Accounts</option>                                                                        
</select>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="filenumber" name = "filenumber" placeholder="Enter file Number" value = "">
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block waves-effect waves-light submit_status" name="submit_status"  type="button">Submit</button>


 </div> <?PHP endforeach; ?>
```

Using Jquery to get the value from the textfeild, select option but shows the same for all text fields.

```
$(".submit_status").click(function (e){
var id = $(".billstatus").val();
var fvcid = $('input[name="fvcid"]').val(); 
var file_number = $('input[name="filenumber"]').val();
});
```

Solution

`<input type = "hidden" name="fvcid" id="fvcid" value="<?PHP echo $getd['id']; ?>"> <input type="text" id="filenumber<?PHP echo $getd['id']; ?>" name = "filenumber" value = "">`

```
<button class="submit_status" name="submit_status"  value = "<?PHP echo $getd['id']; ?>" type="button">Submit</button>

        $(".submit_status").click(function (e){
                    var fvcid = $(this).val();
                    var file_number = $("#filenumber"+fvcid).val();
            });
```

Comment: clicking the <a href = '#' data-toggle='modal' data-animation='bounce' data-target='.fvcmodel".$getd['id']."'>".$getd['code']."</a>

Comment: @Always Helping No it is not working

Comment: <button class="submit_status" name="submit_status"  value = "<?PHP echo $getd['id']; ?>" type="button">Submit</button>

Comment: You never mentioned about getting a value from a button. Not sure why you changed a question and adding that part as well which was not mentioned at all three days ago. Anyways deleted my working answer. It was working exactly as what you asked for.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, so questions should only contain details of the problem itself. If you have a solution, you should post it as an answer to the question.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping You shouldn't delete a working answer, especially if it fixes the problem that was actually described in the question ;) SO is primarily a Q&A for all users, and making sure the answer works specifically for the OP is secondary. This is also why multiple answers are welcomed - if another user has a similar question the accepted answer might not work for them, so other answers might be more suitable for their situation. (And from your comment I'm not sure the OPs solution is going to suit other users with similar questions :) )

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$(this)` selector along with [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method to get the `value` of actual clicked `modal` inputs and select option.

```
$(".submit_status").click(function(e) {
  var id = $(this).siblings(".billstatus").val();
  var fvcid = $(this).siblings('input[name="fvcid"]').val();
  var file_number = $(this).siblings('input[name="filenumber"]').val();
  console.log(id, fvcid, file_number)
});
```

**Working Demo:** (With two different modals)

```js
$(".submit_status").click(function(e) {
  var id = $(this).siblings(".billstatus").val();
  var fvcid = $(this).siblings('input[name="fvcid"]').val();
  var file_number = $(this).siblings('input[name="filenumber"]').val();
  console.log(id, fvcid, file_number)
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-animation="bounce" data-target="#fvcmodel6">Open Modal 6</a>

<div class="modal fade fvcmodel6" id="fvcmodel6" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">`
  <input type="hidden" name="fvcid" id="fvcid" value="6">
  <select name="billstatus" class="form-control form-control-lg billstatus">
    <option value="">Select Status</option>
    <option value="1">Bill Received in Stores</option>
    <option value="2">Returned</option>
    <option value="3">Submitted to Accounts</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="filenumber" name="filenumber" placeholder="Enter file Number" value="">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block waves-effect waves-light submit_status" name="submit_status" type="button">Submit</button>
</div>

<br>
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-animation="bounce" data-target="#fvcmodel9">Open Modal 9</a>

<div class="modal fade fvcmodel9" id="fvcmodel9" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">`
  <input type="hidden" name="fvcid" id="fvcid" value="9">
  <select name="billstatus" class="form-control form-control-lg billstatus">
    <option value="">Select Status</option>
    <option value="1">Bill Received in Stores</option>
    <option value="2">Returned</option>
    <option value="3">Submitted to Accounts</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="filenumber" name="filenumber" placeholder="Enter file Number" value="">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block waves-effect waves-light submit_status" name="submit_status" type="button">Submit</button>
</div>
```